# How do I setup two different View Models to use the same data source in my SwiftUI application?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mvvm

I want to setup a data controller that is shared between 2 or more View Models in my SwiftUI application. I have learned about setting up the data controller as a singleton so that instance is shared between the two but I also have learned singletons are an anti pattern. What are my options?

This is my current attempt that does not work because I believe each VM ends up instantiating its own instance of the user controller. Updating the username in one view does not update in the other view.

UserController

```
@Observable final class UserController {
    
    private(set) var userProfile: UserProfile?
    
    func getUserProfile() async -> () {
        do {
           ...
        } catch {
           ...
        }
    }
    
    func updateUsername(newUsername: String) -> () {
        userProfile?.updateUsername(newUsername: newUsername)
    }
    
}
```

HomeViewModel

```
@Observable final class HomeViewModel {
    
    var controller: UserController
    
    init(controller: UserController) {
        self.controller = controller
    }
    
    func getData() async {
        await controller.getUserProfile()
    }
    
    func updateUsername(newUsername: String) -> () {
        controller.updateUsername(newUsername: newUsername)
    }
}
```

SettingsViewModel

```
@Observable final class SettingsViewModel {
    
    var controller: UserController
    
    init(controller: UserController) {
        self.controller = controller
    }
    
    func getData() async {
        await controller.getUserProfile()
    }
    
    func updateUsername(newUsername: String) -> () {
        controller.updateUsername(newUsername: newUsername)
    }
}
```

In the views, I'm testing this by trying to update the username so it reflects in both views.

HomeView

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State private var vm = HomeViewModel(controller: UserController())
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                if let userProfile = vm.controller.userProfile {
                    Text("\(userProfile.username)")
                }
                
                Button("Get data") {
                    Task {
                        await vm.getData()
                    }
                }
                
                Button("Update username") {
                    vm.updateUsername(newUsername: "HomeViewUsername")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

SettingsView

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @State private var vm = SettingsViewModel(controller: UserController())
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let userProfile = vm.controller.userProfile {
                Text("\(userProfile.username)")
            }
            
            Button("Update username") {
                vm.updateUsername(newUsername: "Settings username")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My goal with this setup is to have a data controller/file that holds all the API requests that are needed and their responses. When I setup a View Model for a screen I can set it up in a way that uses data from a controller that syncs the whole application on updates.

Comment: You'd need to pass an instance of `UsersController` between your views (ie what's known as "dependency injection"). The highest-up view in the hierarchy should own it.

Comment: @jnpdx Does that mean adding the UserController to the environment at a higher level and using it in the view that needs it? I tried that and got an error that "Cannot use instance member 'userController' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" I was grabbing the environment object and trying to setup the ViewModel with that object.

Comment: You need some other setup such as dependency injection or a shared storage.

Comment: @loremipsum If you have time can you share an example? I would definitely like to give you answer credit

Comment: Idk that there is a small project that I could create. Shared storage would be something like CoreData/SwiftData that would refresh the View automatically DI would likely work well this (search for Avanderlee Dependency Injection Swift). There are a ton of ways of tackling this, but the right/best way is really preference/use-case based.

Comment: if you use `.task` and return something from your async func then you dont need any view model objects and can just the `View` struct as the view model as it's designed.

Comment: @malhal I've thought about eliminating the ViewModel all together actually. I can create my UserController that holds all the APIs and variables for managing and updating the user. Inject it into the environment at the appropriate parent level, in this case the tab view. Then I can simply use the at Environment in any main/children view to access the apis or data needed for the screen. Still learning the pros and cons but coming from web development it makes a lot of sense just doing it this way.

Comment: @MobileFirst yes but `UserController` should just have async funcs for returning data it shouldn't have any internal state. The advantage of it been an `EnvironmentKey` is it can be easily swapped for Previews. In SwiftUI state needs to be in the `View` struct hierarchy as lets, states and bindings.

Comment: @malhal The user controller won't hold any state in regards to text fields or toggle bools. But, it will hold the userProfile variable since it will be used in different views. For syncing the user data across multiple screens with the Observable Macro this was the easiest way to get it going.

Comment: Userprofile State needs to be in View structs otherwise it wont update correctly

Comment: I tested with marking the class with Observable and it seemed to work as expected @malhal

Answer (score 0):

Your views should:

- receive a `UserController` instance
- use it to instantiate the ViewModel

Here's and example

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State private var vm: HomeViewModel
    
    init(userController: UserController) {
        _vm = .init(wrappedValue: .init(controller: userController))
    }

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

And of course the same here

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @State private var vm: SettingsViewModel
    
    init(userController: UserController) {
        _vm = .init(wrappedValue: .init(controller: userController))
    }

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

This way the same `UserController` instance will be shared among several ViewModels.

## Update

This is how you create and inject the UserController.

```
@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    private let userController = UserController()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView(userController: userController)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, so with this setup I would need to add the UserController to the environment and when a View is used it is created with that UserController in the environment. In my case HomeView and SettingsView will need to take in the UserController instance from the environment. Did I get that right?

Comment: @MobileFirst No, you cannot leverage `@Environment` because that value is not available yet at `init` time. Instead create 1 single instance of `UserController` in `@main` and then inject it into `Home` (and from there into any other view). I have added an example to my answer.